# Efficiency of using filter{where:} vs. removeAll{where:} when modifying a parameter value

Tags: swift, swift4.2

Swift 4.2 introduced a new [removeAll {where:} function](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0197-remove-where.md). From what I have read, it is supposed to be more efficient than using filter {where:}. I have several scenarios in my code like this:

```
private func getListOfNullDates(list: [MyObject]) -> [MyObject] {
        return list.filter{ $0.date == nil }
            .sorted { $0.account?.name < $1.account?.name }
    }
```

However, I cannot use removeAll{where:} with a param because it is a constant. So I would need to redefine it like this:

```
private func getListOfNullDates(list: [MyObject]) -> [MyObject] {
        var list = list
        list.removeAll { $0.date == nil }
        return list.sorted { $0.account?.name < $1.account?.name }
    }
```

Is using the removeAll function still more efficient in this scenario? Or is it better to stick with using the filter function?

Comment: “Is using the removeAll function still more efficient in this scenario? Or is it better to stick with using the filter function?” why don’t you measure with Instruments and find out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for this question

I've [benchmarked](https://tio.run/##nY7BisIwEEDPzVeMoNCChih7tAdBBE978AOWoU0lkCYlHSsi/vpm03S39aZsICR5ZB6vvaqKPrxXdWMdwcFeTImkrGFMSwJ0Dm@Qw64/U8H5di2@hIg7Y6y0cGcQVtJ/bgmDIoc9kkwzFlmlNEmnzDnwKOMDgTvMBSxgA3kOAh6TRZpycgy4CQJKRxUvQiUtJzfX2NJs2Y9yUrU8msA71CdlCpnGrCxjj1e9HTpwsrbdUy5L/giPF7nT@h/to@Q3fXy/V@79d1FpPLd@9fkD) both functions using this code on TIO:

```
let array = Array(0..<10_000_000)

do {
    let start = Date()
    let filtering = array.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
    let end = Date()

    print(filtering.count, filtering.last!, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
}

do {
    let start = Date()
    var removing = array
    removing.removeAll { $0 % 2 == 0 }
    let end = Date()

    print(removing.count, removing.last!, end.timeIntervalSince(start))
}
```

(To have the `removing` and `filtering` identical, the closure passed to `removeAll` should have been `{ $0 % 2 != 0 }`, but I didn't want to give an advantage to either snippet by using a faster or slower comparison operator.)

And indeed, `removeAll(where:)` is faster when the probability of removing  elements (let's call it `Pr`)is 50%! Here are the benchmark results :

```
filter    : 94ms
removeAll : 74ms
```

This is the same case when `Pr` [is less than 50%](https://tio.run/##jY/RCsIgFECf8ytu0MMGJRY9tiCIoKce@oC4bC4Ep@Fui4h@PXNWW28liHrQw7G@qJLm3qvqZB3Bxp5NgaSsYUxLAnQOr5DBql0TwfliKg5CxJkyVli4MQhj0F6uCYMigzWSTFIWWak0SafMMfAo4y8CNxgJWMLsY4N7L5Km6DUvfAoOSjobz0MojXs911jTcNw@5aQquTWBN6j3yuQyiWVpyu6/kht04GRlm69iNvgQHjdypXXI78uX7Vf@ye887/ru/F@894@81His/WT3BA).

Otherwise, filtering [is faster](https://tio.run/##jY/BCsIgGIDP@RR/0GGDEoMOHVoQRNCpQw8QP5sLwWm4v0VEr545q61bCaJ@6MdnfVElzbxX1ck6go09mwJJWcOYlgToHF4hg1W7JoLzxVQchIgzZaywcGMQxqC9XBMGRQZrJJmkLLJSaZJOmWPgUcZfBG4wErCE@ccG914kTdFrXvgUHJR0Np6HUBr3eq6xpuG4fcpJVXJrAm9Q75XJZRLL0pTdfyU36MDJyjZfxWzwITxu5ErrkN@XL9uv/JPfed713fm/eO8feanxWPvJ7gk) for a higher `Pr`.

One thing to bear in mind is that in your code `list` is mutable, and that opens the possibility for accidental modifications.

Personally, I would choose performance over old habits, and in a sense, this use case is more readable since the intention is clearer.

---

### Bonus : Removing in-place

What's meant by removing *in-place* is the swap the elements in the array in such a way that the elements to be removed are placed after a certain pivot index. The elements to keep are the ones before the pivot element :

```
var inPlace = array
let p = inPlace.partition { $0 % 2 == 0 }
```

Bear in mind that [`partition(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017524-partition) doesn't keep the original order.

This approach [clocks](https://tio.run/##rZFBa8MgFMfP9VO8wQYJpM6WHZdDoRR22mDHMcYjMUUwKuYtY5R@9WVqm2S3Qpkg6t/3fvzE7ks19DAMqnXWE@zsp6mRlDWMaUmA3uM3lLCJayY4f1yJDyHSzBmrLRwYhLGIxR1hQJSwRZJZzlLWKE3SK7MPeYLxUwIHuBVwB2soSxBwnCnS1DPjFLsAoGxC8SpYUjGzucaOborYykm18smEvEf9qkwls6SV5@x4ybdHD162tv@jyxZjwtNGbrS@wn2CnNWn8/@ZK/OisZKzeCx04Xi@4C70qPi1V/iPjKR/vy5G6JuDJazeLz5gGH6qRuO@G5bPvw) better than `removeAll(where:)`

Comment: Great comment, partitioning is underused.

Answer (score 4):

Beware of premature optimization. The efficiency of a method often depends on your specific data and configuration, and unless you're working with a large data set or performing many operations at once, it's not likely to have a significant impact either way. Unless it does, you should favor the more readable and maintainable solution.

As a general rule, just use `removeAll` when you want to mutate the original array and `filter` when you don't. If you've identified it as a potential bottleneck in your program, *then* test it to see if there's a performance difference.